# What is the point of Node.js

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

Ok this is probably a little blunt and to the point, but what is the point/need for Node.js

I've noticed it mainly through CloudFoundry but just not too sure what its supposed to be doing. However I am guessing its probably something pretty big as why else would VMWare be supporting it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's an...

- Efficient and 100% event driven IO framework,
- flexible enough to use the best underlying OS features it can find,
- presenting an API in a high-level programming language (the same language your client-side will most-likely use),
- implemented on top of the best available intepreting engine for that language, and
- supporting more and more third party libraries with each passing day.
- Effecient in server side api, avoid using for CPU intensive operation

:)

Answer (score 14):

Node.js does IO right. It's asynchronous and non-blocking and the beauty of using js is that it does not have a standard blocking IO.

It's fast (v8 is a beast), it scales well, It's got a vibrant community and it's popular.

There are lots of wonderful libraries that run on node like [`now`](http://nowjs.com/) and [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/).

It excels at real time communication and highly concurrent websites.

It also has the added bonus of less code duplication. You can write the same MVC code on the client as the server and easily support non-js users.

Further reads:

- [Usages of Node.js - What obstacles is it aiming to provide a ramp for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506690/usages-of-node-js-what-obstacles-is-it-aiming-to-provide-a-ramp-for/5506770#5506770)
- [Why and when to use Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617683/why-and-when-to-use-node-js/5619188#5619188)
- [What so different about Node.js's event-driven? Can't we do that in ASP.Net's HttpAsyncHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599024/what-so-different-about-node-jss-event-driven-cant-we-do-that-in-asp-nets-htt/5599306#5599306)
- [What is Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)

Answer (score 9):

> Node.js is an event based,
>   asynchronous I/O framework that uses
>   Google's V8 JavaScript engine. Node.js
>   is commonly used for heavy
>   client-server JavaScript applications.

The node.js tag has some more background information to point you in the right direction:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info

Answer (score 7):

Node leverages Javascript's first class functions to allow you to program the server in a dynamic scripting language while getting very competitive performance.

Node isn't as fast as Haskell, Erlang or Go. But it is competitive with Java, and it outperforms Ruby, Python and PHP.

Haskell, Erlang, Go, Java, Ruby, and Python all have evented IO webframeworks, but they also have blocking libraries to serve as pitfalls.

Despite it's warts, Javascript is the lingua franca of the web and since browsers are evented, not only is Javascript built for evented style programming, most web developers are used to writing evented Javascript.

Also check out this register article: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/01/the_rise_and_rise_of_node_dot_js/

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks on haskell & Go being faster?

Comment: http://www.ostinelli.net/a-comparison-between-misultin-mochiweb-cowboy-nodejs-and-tornadoweb/

Comment: http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/3/preliminary-warp-cross-language-benchmarks

Comment: Those cover Haskell & Erlang. I want a statement saying Go is faster then node. The haskell comparisons are also unfair due to not using multiple node processes to scale across cores. I can believe haskell has an edge but its not overwhelming

Comment: I've seen ones that also include Go, but google is ironically bad at searching for Go (or golang since it's mostly referred to as Go)

Comment: Go and Haskell are strongly typed and compiled with multiprocessor concurrency models deeply embedded in the language.  They're faster, they use less memory.  But they're are reasons Node.js has a larger community. (and why I personally use Node.js)

Answer (score 2):

This post might help:

[Why Developers Should Pay Attention to Node.js](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/10/why-developers-should-pay-atte.php)

Comment: That link is dead.