# What can be done with node.js or socket.io?

Tags: sockets, node.js

What can we do with node.js, socket io or any server side JavaScript?

I know every programming language or framework has its own features or functionality that makes it different from other. For example, we use jQuery specially for nice UI design. On that view, what is necessity of learning node.js?

Comment: [Usages of node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506690/usages-of-node-js-what-obstacles-is-it-aiming-to-provide-a-ramp-for/5506770#5506770)

Comment: [Why and when to use node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617683/why-and-when-to-use-node-js/5619188#5619188)

Comment: [What is the point of node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207384/what-is-the-point-of-node-js/6207461#6207461)

Comment: What specifically do you want to know that isn't covered in those questions?