# Server side javascript - General

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)
>   [Usages of Node.js - What obstacles is it aiming to provide a ramp for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506690/usages-of-node-js-what-obstacles-is-it-aiming-to-provide-a-ramp-for)

What is the correct scenario to use server side javascript? like node.js
What kind of problems it solves?

Comment: [6 solid reasons to use node.js](http://raynos.org/blog/19/6-Solid-reasons-to-use-node.js)

Comment: My question was not specific to node.js, but server side script in general. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Node.js solves the problem of serving many concurrent users from I/O based servers.
- By I/O I mean that little to none computation is done in the request response cycle from the 
  server part.
- By concurrent I meany that thousands of users can keep a connection open with the server.
- Having a persistent connection allows real time communication, the server can push over the opened connection, in a sense this way the server can be thought of as initiating the communication (comet, server push).

All this allows having a large user-base with little server resources and real-time communication (chat etc).

Comment: I don't quite understand your point. Is this something like long polling?

Comment: @ZolaKt: yes, node.js works well for long polling

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev: is it used just for long polling, or are there any other significant advantages? If it is only for long polling why not use a COMET approach, why resort to javascript?

Comment: It is used for all sorts of things. Some people serve HTML with it. Use what you're familiar with, not what some guy on the internet tells you to. :-)